# Sequence of probability measures is consistent

Tags: probability, consistency

Denote
$\varphi (y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(y-x)^2}{2}}$. Show that the sequence of probabilit measures $\\$

$P_n(B) = \int...\int_B\varphi(x_1|0)\varphi(x_2|x_1)...\varphi(x_n|x_{n-1})d(x_1)d(x_2)...d(x_n)$

$\\$
is consistent.

I was thinking about using Kolmogorov's Consistency Theorem but I failed with this approach. Maybe somebody has any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can write explicit expressions for these measures: study them.